# Node.js functions

Tags: node.js, express

I use node.js with the express framework and I have figured out how the routing works.

```
app.get('/save',webcalender.save);
```

I have a webcalender file with this function:

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
res.send(req.query["headline"]);};
```

But how would I built a different function and use it in there:

```
exports.test = function() { console.log("test"); }
```

I have tried:

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
    test(); or webcalender.test or also test = webcalender.test(); and then test;
res.send(req.query["headline"]);};
```

thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit unclear.

I assume `save` function is defined in some `webcalendar.js` and imported with

```
var webcalendar = require('./webcalendar.js');
```

Ill break the answer now in two scenarios.

### Assuming `test` function is the same `webcalendar.js`

You can then do something like

```
var test = function() {console.log("test");}
exports.test = test;
```

Or in one line

```
var test = module.exports.test = function() {console.log("test");}
```

And then to use `test` in the same module simply call `test();` like you did.

### In case if `test` is defined in another module

Lets say in `test.js` then in order to use it in `webcalendar.js` module you have to require it like this:

```
var test = require('./test.js').test;
exports.save = function(req, res){
    test();
res.send(req.query["headline"]);};
```

or simply

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
    require('./test.js').test();
res.send(req.query["headline"]);};
```

---

This should cover most of the cases, if its not please clarify your question since as I said earlier its unclear.

Also I suggest you to familiarize your self with [nodejs module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html) to understand why, what and when you need to export, since its not clear from you question why are you exporting the `test` function (in case if its used only in `webcalendar.js` module).
[Here is another good resource](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html) to nodejs require

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much that covered all I needed!